# How to make sure a temp file created by Java program is deleted when cmd is closed abruptly

Tags: java

I am writing a code in java which will create a temporary file for intermittently storing some data and I am executing this program in cmd. I have applied File.deleteOnExit() to the file and it works fine and delete the temporary if I end the program properly.
**My question is that is there a way to make sure that temporary file is deleted if I close the cmd abruptly in middle of the execution?**

Comment: If your program is terminated unexpectedly mid-execution, you can't reliably make sure anything happens.

Comment: You can have other program monitoring health of your and do cleanup in case it detects unexpected termination.